# Change Product Name and thumbnail Image, attach File on the fly in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm new to Wordpress and WooCommerce. I'd really like to do these without a product reference from the database, like adding a product into the cart directly just by passing parameters like how FoxyCart does it, but I don't think WooCommerce can do this. So second option is to add a product into the database, and just update information on the fly. Anyhow, so I'm able to change the price of the product added to the cart in Wordpress with WooCommerce by using the code below.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value['product_id'] == 9 ) {
         $value['data']->price = 500;
    }
    }
}
```

I edited the code so that the price is changed to 500 if the `product_id` is 9. I like this approach because it does not update anything in the database. Now I want to be able to change the product name of the item in the cart too without changing anything in the database.

[image]

The image shows I have `Sample Product` as the product name. I want to be able to change the name. Is there anyway I can do this? I've tried other value names but I can't get the right name. What's the right value name that I should be using? I tried searching in the database and the field name should be `post_title` as the product name, but I'm definitely wrong because it does not work. The `price` field is saved as meta data for posts as a cell value and I don't know how the default code gets this product name. I also would like to attach a file to the product. Is it possible to attach a file? Would it be possible to override the thumbmail image too? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to update the database? Why can you have multiple products each with their respective prices, names, and thumbnails? I'm not familiar with FoxyCart so I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's because the product is all customized. I have coded a browser-based designer that automatically calculates price based on the design created by the user, so nothing is really fixed. The product on the image is just a sample. The final product to be sold is nothing like that. I've separated the web app and this for now for quick debugging. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are doing now. I think you might want to take a close look at the `WC_Cart` class. You can change the item's price/name in the cart via `woocommerce_add_cart_item`. And then "maintain" that change via `woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session`.

Comment: That should work for dynamic values. But then to display the cart differently, you will also need to look at `templates/cart/cart.php`. There are filters such as `woocommerce_cart_item_name` and `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail` that will be relevant.

Comment: Thank you very much Ma'am. I will look into this. All I've done so far was that I added code that gets executed before everything else, thus, if the code finds an ID match, it sets a price before the database price retrieval could even be executed. The only way I've thought of to have really flexible pricing is by using cookies. It works for my purpose. Does WooCommerce support file attachment without 3rd party apps? The attachment is not just for the thumbnail image, but also for the generated file itself.

Comment: Everything Woo does with the cart is stored in `$_SESSION` data. Not sure what you are referring to re: file attachment, but WordPress can handle file uploads. This [Product Designer plugin](http://fancyproductdesigner.com/woocommerce-plugin/) might be helpful. It has good ratings, but I haven't personally used it. I did something similar once and [integrated a 3rd party customizer into WC](http://www.photostarts.com/shop/ezp-product-2/). I think the client took the site live, but my integration is still visible.

Comment: I mean like the custom file created must also be submitted to the seller for reference, the seller does not need the thumbnail image, the seller needs the original file that the thumbnail image is going to be derived from. So the file to be derived from may not necessarily be an image, it might be a vector or something, it depends. Is this possible per product to attach?

Comment: Once you upload the file via WordPress you can do whatever you like with it. And you can associate (either it's URL or attachment ID) it as `order_item_meta` to the order item.

Comment: Thank you very much for this Ma'am. I searched the right field name to change the product name but I failed. Does $cart_object support the product name field like what I did with the price? Like $value['product_name']? I checked the database and the product name is retrieved from the product_id, so WooCommerce is really just joining the tables to get the product name via product id. Could you please guide me more on this? I'm really trying my best but I still can't figure it out. Thank you very much Ma'am.

Comment: I finally managed to change the product name. I used my code above and added a single line of code. I used post_title. However, I still can't figure out the attachment thing. I will research more on this.